# Indexing joined records in Solr

Tags: solr, solr6

I am new to Solr and stuck at something basic (I think), which is probably a lack of understanding/comprehension on my behalf. I've read the documentation on DIH and spent a lot of time searching this issue, without finding my solution.

My use case is a messaging/email system, where users can message each other and start a thread, to which they can reply (so it's more like email than direct messages on a user base).

The question is simple; I have one table, `threads`, that is the base for this and contains searchable data like user info and subject. Then joined from that is the `emails` table, with the `html` column searchable.

When I run below collection in Solr and do a search, it will only pick up a single `email` for a thread and search that, as opposed to what I'm hoping for; get all emails belonging to that thread. So say I have 10 threads, but 100 messages, it says `Fetched: 100`, but `Processed: 10`.

How do I get Solr to index all of this content properly and allow for a search on it? In this particular use case, I have also created a reversed example, getting messages first, then the threads it belongs to and then de-dupe the results (which works to some extent), but the next step is that there is also a `left join` for email attachments. So looking for a solution with this setup.

Using **Solr 6.6**

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="ds-db" type="JdbcDataSource"
                driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                url="${dataimporter.request.url}"
                user="${dataimporter.request.user}"
                password="${dataimporter.request.password}"/>
    <document name="threads">
        <entity name="thread" dataSource="ds-db"
                query="
            SELECT threads.id
                 , threads.user_id
                 , threads.subject
                 , users.first_name
                 , users.last_name
                 , users.email
              FROM threads
         LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id=threads.user_id
            ">
            <field column="id" name="thread_id"/>
            <field column="user_id" name="user_id"/>
            <field column="subject" name="subject"/>
            <field column="first_name" name="first_name"/>
            <field column="last_name" name="last_name"/>
            <field column="email" name="email"/>

            <entity name="message" dataSource="ds-db" transformer="HTMLStripTransformer"
                    query="
                SELECT id
                     , html
                  FROM emails
                 WHERE thread_id = ${thread.id}
                    ">
                <field column="id" name="id"/>
                <field column="html" name="html" stripHTML="true"/>


            </entity>

        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

**managed-schema**

```
<schema name="example-data-driven-schema" version="1.6">
    ...
    <field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="thread_id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="first_name" type="string_lowercase" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="last_name" type="string_lowercase" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="email" type="string_lowercase" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="subject" type="string_lowercase" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="html" type="string_lowercase" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    ...
    <copyField source="first_name" dest="_text_"/>
    <copyField source="last_name" dest="_text_"/>
    <copyField source="email" dest="_text_"/>
    <copyField source="subject" dest="_text_"/>
    <copyField source="html" dest="_text_"/>
    ...
</schema>
```

Comment: What is the definition of the field `html` and its type in your schema?

Comment: @MatsLindh I have updated the question with a snippet from `managed-schema`. Is this what you're asking for?

Comment: I think you're confusing how the entity structure when importing is - the result is a _single document_. Since `html` is single valued, only one value will be inserted. If you make it multiValued, it'll contain every mail associated with the thread. If you want one document per mail in a thread, you probably want to do a join with the html as well and get one document per mail w/its metadata.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment that I've just deleted, it works now! I can also see all of the HTMLs in an array in Solr, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the emails in a single field, that field has to be set as `multiValued="true"` - otherwise you'll only get one of the dependent entities indexed.